# Set compiler specific settings and project build location in eclipse via cmake file

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, cmake

I have a C/C++ project I'm maintaining with CMake and I use the eclipse IDE for it.At the moment, each time I invoke the CMake from "scratch" (that generates Makefiles for the entire project - executable and some libraries) I need to do two specific settings in the eclipse in order it to work (compile and build the project successfully).

1) I need to set the build location:[image: build_location_after_my_edit]

NOTE: I added "manually" the build at the end of the "build directory" entry.

2) I need to set some specific flag for the "Command to get compiler specs":

[image: command_to_get_compiler_specs_after_my_edit]

NOTE: I added "manually" the "-std=c++11" flag.

My quesiton then is - can I do this via the CMake files in order that I won't need to add these two specific settings manually each time I'm re-running CMake ?

I use:

a) CMake version 3.5.1

b) Eclipse Kepler

Thanks,

Guy.

Comment: For using IDEs with CMake, you need to use the right "Generator".  If you run in the terminal `cmake -G` it will show you the ones available.  So `cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"` is probably what you want, in the same directory as the top level `CMakeLists.txt`.  However, this is exactly what Eclipse does for you when using the GUI, it's probably best to stick with that ;)  See [the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/generator/Eclipse%20CDT4.html), they already setup an out-of-source build for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding the `-std=c++11` problem you are able to fix that with adding the following 2 lines to your CMakeLists.txt file

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

I poorly don't know a solution to adding the build directory manually, but the normal behavior without an IDE would be to create a build director change into that dir and run a cake .. in it

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```